# lenovo yoga pad actionbar icon issue in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I have lenovo yoga pad tablet and i have an android application installed on it. Application is working fine in all other devices but in lenovo yoga pad action bar icon is missing. Icon wan not displaying in this device.

Can any one please let me know what is the issue

Thanks,

sathish

Comment: Yep, got that issue too. I have lenovo yoga tablet 8 with Android 4.2.2. I develop my own application with support of actions bar (native), I use Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar theme and still... No action bar icon on this tablet.

Comment: User reported to me exactly the same problem on the same device for my app.